# Difficulty with simple ASP rewrite rule

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, url-rewriting

I have the page:

```
~/forum/forum_faq.html
```

In my logs I've seen 404 requests to:

```
~/forum_faq.html
```

For some reason, so I attempt to fix it with this rule:

```
<rewrite url="~/forum_faq.html$" to="~/Handlers/PermRedirect.ashx?URL=forum/forum_faq.html" processing="stop" />
```

The perm redirect file just does a 301 redirect to the given location.  When this rule isn't there, I can access forum/forum_faq.html just fine.  When I add the rule, I get a:

> This web page has a redirect loop The web page at
>   http://127.0.0.1/forum/forum_faq.html has resulted in too many
>   redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party
>   cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server
>   configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: where is the handler coded to redirect if the url is "~/forum_faq.html$" ?

Comment: Is forum an ASP.Net application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is suspect what is happening is `Forum` is an ASP.NET application in IIS. Your `~/forum_faq.html$` is therefore matching the path `/forums/forum_faq.html` sending it via your handler which then redirects to `/forum/forum_faq.html` in an infinite loop.